# Return dynamic file with JQuery and ASHX with POST parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, download

Hi I need to generate some files on server side and return them to client with AJAX

I create next code on server (ASHX)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string dataViewID = context.Request.Form["dataViewID"];

        MyService service = new MyService();
        var data = service.GetStores(int.Parse(dataViewID), "", null);
        IMyExportService exportservice = new MyExportService();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "export.cvs");  

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                exportservice.ExportTo("csv", sw, data);                
                ms.Position = 0;                                                
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ms.ToArray());
            }

        }
    }
```

on client i create next code: 
$("#btnexport").click(function () {
          var paramData = { "dataViewID": 1524129, "filter": "", extent: null }; //full map
        $.ajax({
            url: '/marketVuePortal/'+'FileExport.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {dataViewID:1524129},
            success: function (result) {
                //what should be here ?
            },
             error: function (xhr) {
             alert("error");
           }
    }
    )}

```
);
```

But I have 2 problem I don't know why but I always get error but in debug all code working well. and second is that I don't know how to say browser that he need save page with out reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /*  *
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------  * jQuery-Plugin - $.download - allows for simple get/post requests for files  * by Scott Jehl, scott@filamentgroup.com  *
>   http://www.filamentgroup.com  * reference article:
>   http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/
>   * Copyright (c) 2008 Filament Group, Inc  * Dual licensed under the MIT (filamentgroup.com/examples/mit-license.txt) and GPL
>   (filamentgroup.com/examples/gpl-license.txt) licenses.  *
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------  */   jQuery.download = function(url, data, method){     //url and data options required     if( url && data ){          //data can be string of
>   parameters or array/object        data = typeof data == 'string' ? data :
>   jQuery.param(data);       //split params into form inputs         var inputs =
>   '';       jQuery.each(data.split('&'), function(){            var pair =
>   this.split('=');          inputs+='';        });         //send request      jQuery(''+inputs+'')
>         .appendTo('body').submit().remove();    }; };

This is solution that I have found.